# Type declarations on implemented method which has no type declarations

Tags: php, php-7

I have an interface like so:

```
interface A {
    static function from($object): self;
}
```

In the class that implements the interface:

```
class B implements A {
    static function from(\C $object): self{ // This is highlighted as an error
        return new self();
    }
}
```

Can I not declare a type when the interface has not declared a type?

Comment: Why you just don't read official documentation [PHP Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), this really "some times" helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I not declare a type when the interface has not declared a type?

In short: no.

As per the docs for [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) (which seem pretty clear to me):

> The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error.

If you provided more detail as to why you think you need to do this, we could perhaps give a more helpful answer, but yer just asking a yes/no question, and the answer to that is - as I said - "no".